# getType() method not found in antlr4

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

The rule below is an extract from the larger rule. Notice the optional part at the tail end of the grammar. After the input is parsed, we walk the generated parsed tree to evaluate the expression. The listener code for the first rule is also given below.

```
arithmeticTerm
   : arithmeticFactor (op=(MULT|DIVIDE) arithmeticFactor)*
   ;

arithmeticFactor: INTEGER        /* For now , let it be simple terminal */
```

Listener

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.NotNull;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeProperty;

public class PredicateEvaluator extends PredicateGrammarBaseListener {

    private ParseTreeProperty<Float> floatValues = new ParseTreeProperty<Float>();
    private ArrayList<Float> arithmeticTermFactorList = null;

    private void setFloatValue(ParseTree node, float value){ 
       floatValues.put(node, value); 
    }

    private float getFloatValue(ParseTree node){
       return floatValues.get(node); 
    }

    public void enterArithmeticTerm(
      @NotNull PredicateGrammarParser.ArithmeticTermContext ctx) 
    { 
       arithmeticTermFactorList = new ArrayList<Float>();
    }
```

Currently, I am evaluating the arithmetic term in this way. I need to detect the type op and either divie or multipy the factors. But, the my compiler cannot find the getType() method. I looked at the antlr4 generated codes but it was not there. I am following the book by the creator of antlr4 and he uses the getType() method in the similar scenario, but the same thing is not working here. Your help will be really appreicated.

```
    public void exitArithmeticTerm(
      @NotNull PredicateGrammarParser.ArithmeticTermContext ctx) 
    { 
        float evaluatedValue = 0.0f;        
        if (ctx.op == null){
            evaluatedValue = getFloatValue(ctx.arithmeticFactor().get(0));
        }else{
            for(float value : arithmeticTermFactorList){
                if(ctx.op.getType() == PredicateGrammarLexer.MULT) {
                    evaluatedValue *= value;  
                }else{
                    evaluatedValue /= value;    
                }  
            }
        }
        arithmeticExprTermList.add(evaluatedValue);
    }

    public void exitArithmeticFactor(
      @NotNull PredicateGrammarParser.ArithmeticFactorContext ctx) 
    {  
      Float evaluatedValue = NEGATIVE * Integer.valueOf(ctx.INTEGER().getText());  
      arithmeticTermFactorList.add(evaluatedValue);
    }
```

}

Comment: I think it's because `ctx.op` is an array. This it's because it can be matched zero or more times.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing:

```
arithmeticTerm
   : arithmeticFactor (op=(MULT|DIVIDE) arithmeticFactor)*
   ;
```

do something like this:

```
expression
 : MINUS expression              #unaryMinusExpression
 | expression MULT expression    #multExpression
 | expression DIVIDE expression  #divideExpression
 | expression ADD expression     #addExpression
 | expression MINUS expression   #minusExpression
 | INTEGER                       #integerExpression
 | '(' expression ')'            #parensExpression
 ;
```

And then in your listener, you simply have to override the `#...Expression` methods:

```
@Override
public void enterMultExpression(@NotNull PredicateGrammarParser.MultExpressionContext ctx) 
{ 
    ...
}
```

Note that `MULT` and `DIVIDE` expressions have a higher precedence than `ADD` and `MINUS` since they are defined before the latter.